# EnumWindows does not detect windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, window

I am trying to use EnumWindows to print out the titles of all visible windows.

It was working at first, EnumWindows was calling the callback function createWindow() multiple times with each call of EnumWindows. But without adding any meaningful code it stopped working and now only calls createWindow() once with a handle of a not visible window.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int row = 2;
    int col = 2;

    vector<Window> detectedWindows((row * col) + 4);

    EnumWindows(&createWindow, (LPARAM)&detectedWindows);
}

BOOL CALLBACK createWindow(HWND input, LPARAM storage)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(input))
    {
        TCHAR titleTchar[30];

        GetWindowText(input, titleTchar, 30);

        wcout << titleTchar << endl;

        CString titleCstr = titleTchar;
        CT2CA converting(titleCstr);
        string title(converting);

        cout << title << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are no recorded error messages. GetLastError returns 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your callback returns `FALSE` so `EnumWindows()` stops enumerating windows. Have it return `TRUE` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the return value is not used for anything.

Comment: @ColdZer0 That is what you get for not reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows): "*EnumWindows continues until the last top-level window is enumerated **or the callback function returns FALSE**.*" And the [EnumWindowsProc callback documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633498.aspx) also says: "*To continue enumeration, the callback function must return TRUE; **to stop enumeration, it must return FALSE**.*"