# Unexpected behavior when returning FALSE on winapi CALLBACK function (loop gets skipped?)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, callback

I have the following function. If the return on the bottom of the function is `TRUE` works as expected.

But if I change it to `FALSE` ( to know if regex_match yield a result) it seems to completely skip the for loop and returns `FALSE` directly. I'm very un-familiar with winapi so i might been using return value unappropriate.

I tried both g++ and msvc w/o optimizer, but got the same behavior.

```cpp
BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {

    static const std::wregex rgx(L"(.+) - (?!\\{)(.+)");
    const auto &paramRe = *reinterpret_cast<EnumWindowsProcParam*>(lParam);

    DWORD winId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &winId);

    for (DWORD pid : (paramRe.pids)) {
        if (winId == pid) {
            std::wstring title(GetWindowTextLength(hwnd) + 1, L'\0');
            GetWindowTextW(hwnd, &title[0], title.size()); //note: >=C++11 

            std::regex_match(title, rgx);
            std::wsmatch matches;

            if (std::regex_search(title, matches, rgx)) {
                paramRe.song = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().to_bytes(matches[1]);
                paramRe.artist = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().to_bytes(matches[2]);
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return TRUE;  // <--- HERE
}
```

Idk, if rest of the code matters, but as said if default return value is true the code works as intended I just don't know if match was found (I know I could check if value of strings change, or pass that info to the lparam struct I use, but that still raises the question why is that happening.)

Comment: @RbMm So when I call EnumWindows(enumWindowsProc, ..) It does multiple enumerations with different `hwd`'s ?

Comment: yes, EnumWindows function enumerates all top-level windows on the screen . return false mean stop enumeration. if you need return some result for caller - do this via *EnumWindowsProcParam - paramRe*

Comment: Oh, Is see that makes sense. I thought it was getting the "appropriate" window. I should I would pass the result to `EnumWindowsProcParam as said`. Also I guess It would be efficient to add the FALSE inside the if statement to stop the enumeration then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EnumWindows does not detect windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602526/enumwindows-does-not-detect-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `CALLBACK` is just the function calling convention and has nothing to do with when the enumeration stops.

MSDN clearly says:

> `EnumWindows` continues until the last top-level window is enumerated or the callback function returns FALSE.

If you need to record some specific information regarding finding a match then you should store that in the struct you pass as the `LPARAM` parameter.

If you only care about the first window that matches then you can return `FALSE` once that window is found, this aborts the enumeration without having to inspect the remaining windows.