# EnumWindows Behavior

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, windows-rs

[I've been using MSDN for the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows), and I've also found [EnumChildWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows), [the rust documentation is a stub](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/UI/WindowsAndMessaging/fn.EnumWindows.html).
My question is what the behavior of EnumWindows *actually* is.
I've been under the impression that it enumerates calling the provided function with every top level (application) window but right now all I'm getting is *default ime*.

HWNDS_LENGTH is just a magic number for the size of a static array used to store the id for each window at startup.  This should never be more than four in use.  HWNDS_COLLECTION is a static array used to store all window ids found at startup.  These are minor details that only exist to receive the ids from the callback (I know this is working because I successfully read the title of one window).

```
const HWNDS_LENGTH: usize = 20; // Never going to use all this
static mut HWNDS_COLLECTION: [Option<HWND>; HWNDS_LENGTH] = [None; HWNDS_LENGTH];
```

My callback fills in the array, backwards, with the window ids leaving the front empty (None).  This returns true always so I don't think that a false return value would cause enumeration to stop early.

```
unsafe extern "system" fn enumeration_callback(hwnd: HWND, _: LPARAM) -> BOOL {
    for i in HWNDS_LENGTH..0 {
        match HWNDS_COLLECTION[i] {
            Some(_) => {}
            None => {HWNDS_COLLECTION[i] = Some(hwnd); break}
        }
    }
    HWNDS_COLLECTION[0] = Some(hwnd);
    BOOL::from(true)
}
```

tracked_windows is the vector that all window ids are copied into from the static memory.
Other than that what is at concern is just the call to EnumWindows and unpacking of the ids. There's a lot more code to this but it's proprietary and application specific.

```
fn main() -> () {
    let mut tracked_windows = vec![];
    unsafe {
        EnumWindows(Some(enumeration_callback), LPARAM(*&0)).expect("Failed to get windows");
        for x in HWNDS_COLLECTION {
            match x {
                None => {}
                Some(y) => {
                    match query_window(y) {
                        true => {tracked_windows.push(y)}
                        false => {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding a print statement into the callback to print the title of the window as it was collected and it only received one, this would imply to me that it's enumerating over the single top level window which I don't see being useful at all and not what is implied by the documentation. I want to know what this function does. I'd like to know what I'm doing or what I need to do but those are *not* the question that I'm asking and aren't useful.

[enumwindows does not detect windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602526/enumwindows-does-not-detect-windows) looks like a duplicate from the title, but the solution there was simply returning false which my code does not (unless BOOL::from(true) somehow gets interpreted as false due to magic).

Comment: The function enumerates top level windows, no more, no less. Top level windows are windows without the `WS_CHILD` style bit set. There are normally hundreds of top level windows in the system at any one time, mostly not visible. I'm not familiar with rust but to me your enumeration logic looks kind of odd. Why not just fill in the array from 0 to X? What's the loop for in the enum callback?

Comment: nit: You should practically never use `static mut`. Use a mutex in a non-mut static, then you can even use a `Vec` instead of an array.

Comment: nit: You can just do `LPARAM::default()` instead of `LPARAM(&*0)`

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks for the default, I read through the documentation and was slightly annoyed that I had to essentially cast from null reference to LPARAM (which is slightly obfuscated from C++). Also thanks for the const static mutex, I've avoided smart pointers where I haven't needed them and didn't realize it was a constant reference to a mutable value.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for explaining what a top level window was, I need to read over more... I'm only getting one value, rust question on syntax that I'm about to look up, am I rather than counting down counting up until reset or something so I'm collecting one value... Also, to the question asked, if you were to explain the WS_CHILD defining what a top level window was then that would answer the question. Thanks

Comment: @PitaJ So, all I did was apply your nitpicks and it works now lol, at least insofar as it's clear what's happening. Thanks

Comment: @TimothyH "*... if you were to explain the WS_CHILD defining what a top level window was ...*" - see [Window Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features) and [Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) on MSDN

Comment: [`EnumWindows()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) accepts a user-supplied context argument (`lParam`). You can pass anything along that suits your needs, such as a `*mut Vec<HWND>` pointer, and have the callback [`append()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append) to it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau had typed that as in it would be the accepted answer to the question.

Comment: @IInspectable That's what I thought and is what I've done before in C++, but when I tried passing the reference through lParam, in my callback there was a compiler error because of casting to the actual type it was.  How should I do that in Rust?

Comment: The EnumWindows function enumerates all the top-level windows on the screen by passing the handle to each window to an application-defined callback function. Enumeration Windows will continue until the last top-level window or the callback function returns FALSE.